# compiling kernel -- 3.9.4 -- issues

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fedora

I have a desktop on which fedora linux is installed. Kernel i am using is `3.9.4` .
I need to recompile my 3.9.4 kernel for CAN bus support.

My kernel source is here :---

```
[root@localhost 3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64]# pwd
/usr/src/kernels/3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64
```

Then i did -- `make menuconfig`, -- changed the configuration.

Error i get after -- `make`.

```
[root@localhost 3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64]# make
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/kernels/3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

How to get rid of this error to compile my kernel ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the entire source tree for the kernel.  /usr/src/kernels/3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64/ does not contain the entire source for the Fedora kernel, it only contains headers and makefiles for building additional modules.

You can either get the source rpm for that kernel and rebuild it.  Or get a mainline kernel directly from kernel.org and build it.